# Stripe webhook error fails on wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I am trying to solve a problem, I am currently doing tests with stripe where the user pays for a small percentage of a reservation, this payment is reflected in my stripe account (test) and everything is in order. The problem is that there is an event that fails and it is retried to send from webhook, when this event is retried to send it causes me on the web page to be marked as fully paid, the ideal would be that this event always comes out as successful or that it does not return to try, hope there is a solution.

[image: Stripe webhook log]

This is the code from the theme when the function take place of payment_intent.succeeded:

```
$endpoint_secret   =   esc_html ( wprentals_get_option('wp_estate_stripe_webhook','') ); 
$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
        $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
    exit('');
} catch(\Stripe\Error\SignatureVerification $e) {
    // Invalid signature
    http_response_code(400); // PHP 5.4 or greater
    exit();
}
   
    

if ($event->type == "payment_intent.succeeded") {
        $intent = $event->data->object;
  
        $pay_type       =   intval($event->data->object->charges->data[0]->metadata->pay_type);
        $userId         =   intval($event->data->object->charges->data[0]->metadata->user_id);  
        $depozit        =   intval($intent->amount);
       
            
        if($pay_type==1){
            
            $invoice_id     =   intval($event->data->object->charges->data[0]->metadata->invoice_id);
            $booking_id     =   intval($event->data->object->charges->data[0]->metadata->booking_id );
        
            $is_stripe=1;
            wpestate_booking_mark_confirmed($booking_id,$invoice_id,$userId,$depozit,$user_email,$is_stripe);
            $redirect=wpestate_get_template_link('user_dashboard_my_reservations.php');
            http_response_code(200);
            wp_redirect($redirect);exit();
        
            
        }else if($pay_type==2){
            
            $listing_id     =   intval($event->data->object->charges->data[0]->metadata->listing_id);
            $is_featured    =   intval($event->data->object->charges->data[0]->metadata->featured_pay);
            $is_upgrade     =   intval($event->data->object->charges->data[0]->metadata->is_upgrade);

            $time = time(); 
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time);

            if($is_upgrade==1){
                update_post_meta($listing_id, 'prop_featured', 1);
                $invoice_id = wpestate_insert_invoice('Upgrade to Featured','One Time',$listing_id,$date,$current_user->ID,0,1,'' );
                update_post_meta($invoice_id, 'invoice_status', 'confirmed');
                wpestate_email_to_admin(1);
            }else{
                update_post_meta($listing_id, 'pay_status', 'paid');
                $admin_submission_status = esc_html ( wprentals_get_option('wp_estate_admin_submission','') );
                $paid_submission_status  = esc_html ( wprentals_get_option('wp_estate_paid_submission','') );

                if($admin_submission_status=='no'  && $paid_submission_status=='per listing' ){
                    $post = array(
                        'ID'            => $listing_id,
                        'post_status'   => 'publish'
                        );
                    $post_id =  wp_update_post($post ); 
                }
                // end make post publish

                if($is_featured==1){
                    update_post_meta($listing_id, 'prop_featured', 1);
                    $invoice_id = wpestate_insert_invoice('Publish Listing with Featured','One Time',$listing_id,$date,$current_user->ID,1,0,'' );
                    update_post_meta($invoice_id, 'invoice_status', 'confirmed');
                }else{
                    $invoice_id = wpestate_insert_invoice('Listing','One Time',$listing_id,$date,$current_user->ID,0,0,'' );
                    update_post_meta($invoice_id, 'invoice_status', 'confirmed');
                }
                wpestate_email_to_admin(0);
            }
        
            $redirect = wpestate_get_template_link('user_dashboard.php');
            http_response_code(200);
            wp_redirect($redirect);exit();
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "the ideal would be that this event always comes out as successful or that it does not return to try"? When an event is marked as `failed` that means that something has gone wrong and you have not yet done any processing w/ the event (so you likely haven't marked anything paid). Wouldn't you want Stripe to resend these events so you could properly process them?

Comment: For some reason that I do not know, even if it appears as a failed request, it has the desired effect (subtract the percentage that I established from the total amount), however, as this request "failed", when stripe resend the request automatically and for another reason that I do not know, it appears as fully paid, i know this by giving resend request manually.

Comment: So my "solution" was to disable those automatic requests which I did not know how to do or that they are properly marked as successful.Actually the estate code of the request is 302(found)